# SOAP Webservice - error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to create a user-defined SOAP Webservice using nusoap with the following codes:

service.php

```
<?php
require 'nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';
require 'fetchdata.php';

$server = new nusoap_server(); 
$server->configureWSDL("Book Info Service","urn:soaptest"); 
$server->register(
    "get_info", 
    array("input"=>"xsd:string"),  
    array("return"=>"xsd:string")  
);


$server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));

?>
```

fetchdata.php

```
<?php

function get_info($input)
{
    $books = [
        "9780435910105"=>["Opening Spaces: An Anthology of Contemporary African Women's Writing","Yvonne Vera","Heinemann"],
        "9780394721170"=>["African Folktales","Roger D. Abrahams","Knopf Doubleday Publishing Group"],
        "9781558615007"=>["Women Writing Africa: West Africa and the Sahel","Esi Sutherland-Addy","Feminist Press at CUNY"]
    ];
    
    foreach($books as $isbn=>$info)
    {
        if($isbn==$input)
        {
            return "<b>Title:</b> ".$info[0]."<br /><br /><b>Author:</b> ".$info[1]."<br /><br /><b>Publisher:</b> ".$info[2];
            break;
        }
                                    
    }
        return "No information found for"." ".$input;        
}

?>
```

When I run it locally, the WSDL page throws an error and the rest of the page is blank

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Why is this happening?
I want to integrate this into an app so I need the WSDL link.

I honestly just copied and modified this so I don't really know what is happening.
Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: you've to verify the source code of the response, you can do so in the browser console. Perhaps even the response headers could help already, if it's not 200 but perhaps 4xx or 5xx.

Comment: @David Thank you for commenting. It seems like there is no response.
Here's what I found in the browser console:
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasAttribute')
    at global-shortcut.js:10:27
    at global-shortcut.js:10:378
Can you help with what I should do to solve this?

Comment: I don't know if the "urn:soaptest" is a variable for a URL, at least there you need a URL that is delivering the expected content. And if "urn:soaptest" is a local address, you've to check why that's not working.